# Find all resource with specific extension from jar programmatically

Tags: java, resources, jar, yaml, application-resource

I have a function which gets object of some type as it parameter.  I have to get all the resource files having extension `.yml` from that location.

How to do it?

Comment: do you want to get list of files in jar with extn of .yml?

Comment: Who puts the `.yml` in the Jar? Get them to include a list of the files at a known place in the Jar.  e.g.  `resources/yml-list.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of this code

```
JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("my.jar");

    for(Enumeration<JarEntry> em = jarFile.entries(); em.hasMoreElements();) {  
        String s= em.nextElement().toString();

        if(s.startsWith(("path/to/resource/directory/"))){
            ZipEntry entry = jarFile.getEntry(s);

            String fileName = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1, s.length());
            if(fileName.endsWith(".yml")){
                InputStream inStream= jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
                int c;
                while ((c = inStream.read()) != -1){
                    out.write(c);
                }
                inStream.close();
                out.close();

            }
        }
    }  
    jarFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FileFilter` to filter out `.yaml` files. [This](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/java/how-implement-java-filefilter-list-files-directory) post gives an example of how to implement and use a one.

Comment: A `FileFilter` does not work for resources in a Jar.  They are `JarEntry` not `File` instances.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the phrasing of the question is a bit unclear, but if I understand it correctly, you want to extract all files with a .yml file extension from a given jar.

If this is the case, you could simply instantiate a java.util.JarFile from the known jar file path and use [getEntries()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html#entries%28%29). This method returns an enumeration of JarEntries which you could iterate through and verify that their names end with ".yml".